# How to move to next activity after login success

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I finally got my login and registration to work. Once I get a success on login, how do I move to the next activity? I thought I put the Intent in the right place in the PostExecute, but it's not moving forward. Can you take a look and assist?

LoginActivity.java

```js
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    public static final String EMAIL = "EMAIL";

    public static final String PASSWORD = "PASSWORD";

    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://www.contrariantradefx.info/android/btfxalerts/login.php";

    private EditText editTextEmail;
    private EditText editTextPassword;

    private Button buttonLogin;
    private Button buttonRegister;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);

        buttonLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);
        buttonRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);

        buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    private void login(){
        String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
        userLogin(email,password);
    }

    private void userLogin(final String email, final String password){
        class UserLoginClass extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
            ProgressDialog loading;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(LoginActivity.this,"Please Wait",null,true,true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                s = s.trim();
                if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("success")){
                    **Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,GoogleInAppBilling.class);
                    intent.putExtra(email,email);
                    startActivity(intent);**
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                HashMap<String,String> data = new HashMap<>();
                data.put("email",params[0]);
                data.put("password",params[1]);

                RegisterUserClass ruc = new RegisterUserClass();//todo leave class here but we are not using this to register

                String result = ruc.sendPostRequest(LOGIN_URL,data);

                return result;
            }
        }
        UserLoginClass ulc = new UserLoginClass();
        ulc.execute(email, password);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v == buttonLogin){
        login();

     buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UserRegistration.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
  };
}
}
```

RegisterUserClass

```js
}else{
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: What do you mean by its not moving forward? Is there a crash or nothing happens after login?

Comment: call `finish()` after `startActivity(intent)`

Comment: kabuto178 - the login is successful, but the screen does not change to the next activity, which would be the googleinappbilling activity. it just stays on the same page. no crash.

Comment: stankovitch - thanks! I will add that and check it out.

Comment: what is returned from `String result = ruc.sendPostRequest(LOGIN_URL,data);`.  That seems to be pivotal for the process to progress but you have a note like it's a placeholder.

Comment: Anthony - That class wasn't well explained in the tutorial. I know it has the HTTP connection information in it to help registration. I didn't use it for the registration as I followed an updated tutorial from the same site that didn't require it.

Comment: Do you know if it gets to the `startActivity`? If not, can you put a Log in the if block and the else block to make sure its getting there?

Comment: Daniel Kobe - I will add the log to see if it is getting there

Comment: I got it to work. I replaced if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("success")){. I matched the success message case and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If your response from Back end is in Json Foramt parse response like this

```
            @Override 
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                try{
                JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(s);
                if (jObject.has("success")) {
                    **Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,GoogleInAppBilling.class);
                    intent.putExtra(email,email);
                    startActivity(intent);**
                }else{ 
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } 
            } 
            catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

             loading.dismiss();
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
}else{
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```